# How to change smoothing method of Naive Bayes classifier in NLTK？

Tags: python, machine-learning, nltk, bayesian, smoothing

I have trained a spam classifier using NLTK Naive Bayes method. Both the spam set and not spam set have 20,000 instances of words in training.

I have noticed that when encountering an unknown features, the `classifier` gives it `0.5` probability of spam:

```
>>> print classifier.prob_classify({'unkown_words':True}).prob('spam')
0.5
```

I know that this is called [`Laplace Smoothing`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplacian_smoothing) in Bayes classification. However, I want to set the spam probability of [unknown features](http://www.paulgraham.com/spam.html) to `0.4`, because the unknown features are more probably is from the normal users. How can I implement it with NLTK?

Comment: This is actually not Laplace Smoothing; The mathematics behind why you obtained a 0.5 probability is explained in the NLTK book itself (http://www.nltk.org/book/ch06.html) as well as the NLTK.naivebayes source code (http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/classify/naivebayes.html). Specifically, the source code's comment said "If the classifier encounters an input with a feature that has
    never been seen with any label, then rather than assigning a
    probability of 0 to all labels, it will ignore that feature."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a really simple way to solve this problem.

I selected 12,000 spam accounts and 18,000 normal accounts to re-train the Naive Bayes classifier. The proportion of spam account and normal accounts is 0.4 / 0.6.

So when the classifier receives an unknown feature of the training set, it give 0.4 probability of spam:

```
In [23]: classifier.prob_classify({'unknown_words': True}).prob('spam')
Out[23]: 0.40000333322222587
```

Comment: did you find a way to find out of NLTK naive Bayes does a computation? Can you answer [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27897591/python-nltk-naive-bayes-classifier-what-is-the-underlying-computation-that-this)?